# Why parsing this JSON string using JSONObject give me an error?

Tags: android, json

I have this code

```
String resultStr = result.getString("result");
String testStr = "{\"movielens\":{\"searchMovie\":{\"code\":400,\"data\":\"Access Denied\"}}}";
Log.e("result", resultStr);
Log.e("teststr", testStr);
JSONObject testJson = new JSONObject(testStr);
JSONObject resultJson = new JSONObject(resultStr);
```

which normally parsing json from the web.
The testStr here is the string that i copy in the logcat by hand and try to put it to test if it is error or not.

and this is the result :

```
02-13 12:16:44.570: E/json result(23439): {"statusCode":200,"result":"﻿{\"movielens\":{\"searchMovie\":{\"code\":400,\"data\":\"Access Denied\"}}}","success":true}
02-13 12:16:44.575: E/result(23439): ﻿{"movielens":{"searchMovie":{"code":400,"data":"Access Denied"}}}
02-13 12:16:44.575: E/teststr(23439): {"movielens":{"searchMovie":{"code":400,"data":"Access Denied"}}}
02-13 12:16:44.575: W/System.err(23439): org.json.JSONException: Value ﻿ of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
02-13 12:16:44.580: W/System.err(23439):    at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:107)
02-13 12:16:44.580: W/System.err(23439):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:158)
02-13 12:16:44.585: W/System.err(23439):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
02-13 12:16:44.585: W/System.err(23439):    at com.abac.recommender.movielensdemo.BaseActivity$MakeRequest.onPostExecute(BaseActivity.java:176)
02-13 12:16:44.585: W/System.err(23439):    at com.abac.recommender.movielensdemo.BaseActivity$MakeRequest.onPostExecute(BaseActivity.java:1)
```

It always error at this line `JSONObject resultJson = new JSONObject(resultStr);`
which is the json i get from the web but why testStr is not error when convert it to json? Both string look identical?

So i test equality for them like this

```
Log.e("compare", "" + resultStr.equals(testStr));
```

and i get

```
02-13 12:25:20.940: E/compare(23912): false
```

So, what are the difference and how can i get this to work?

Thanks.

Comment: you need to create `JSONObject testJson = new JSONObject(testStr);` only why are you creating two `JSONObject`?

Comment: What is your exact response of JSON ?

Comment: @M D, I create testJson because i want to know the cause of the error. The resultStr that i want to convert to json is give me an error. @GrlsHu, the data is "{\"movielens\":{\"searchMovie\":{\"code\":400,\"data\":\"Access Denied\"}}}" in the first line log but i put that into a my own json as a string for return in doInBackground. So data from web(json format) put that in my json together with success flag, status code and return to onPost.. where i get an error.

Comment: Why are you comparing strings? There's probably some extra character that doesn't show up when you Log the strings but it makes the string comparison fail. Shouldn't you be parsing the JSON using JSONObject and then check for equality or for the presence of a specific property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some times what happen when you are fetching data from the server at that time some un-wanted characters was added when you compose the String. So try this it will help you.

Instead of return only ***json*** object change from

```
return urJsonObject;
```

to

```
return new JSONObject(json.substring(json.indexOf("{"), json.lastIndexOf("}") + 1)
```